# Git LFS "Object does not exist on the server" because it's trying to find old file not tracked by LFS?

Tags: git-lfs

I set up LFS for extension ".pdf" on machine 1, and I am getting this error upon git pull on machine 2 `[404] Object does not exist on the server` for a specific file "test.pdf". This file is not tracked by LFS because it's an old file, and afaik old files are not tracked by LFS even if it matches the extension.

Maybe I am wrong but I think it's because I had 'test.pdf' file in origin/master that I hadn't pulled on machine 2 before I set up LFS. So "git pull" is trying to look for test.pdf that is not actually on LFS because it was an old file on master that is not tracked by LFS. In this case how can I successfully git pull? E.g. just get this file on machine 2 from origin (I don't mind if it is not on LFS) by making the local repo up date with the commit just before LFS was set up, and then git pull all the LFS stuff. Or somehow manually add 'test.pdf' to LFS, if that is the simplest option? Sorry if this doesn't make sense. You'd think git would be able to handle this but it seems to be happening because test.pdf does not exist in machine 2 and it's confused because it's not on LFS (it wouldn't be because I didn't put it there).

Edit: clarity

Comment: You're mixing up Git-LFS (which is *not* Git) with plain Git (which *is* Git). Git-LFS sort of "surrounds" Git and works by lying to it, strategically. Git then consults Git-LFS at various points to get files from the (separate) LFS server, or put files onto the LFS server. You'll need to figure out why Git-LFS is lying to Git saying that this file is on the LFS server and that Git needs to ask Git-LFS to get it *from* that server, if it's not actually *on* that server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean when you say "lying"? I know that git is not Git LFS, they just communicate with each other right? I think Git LFS thinks this file is on LFS because the file extension is ".pdf" but this particular file is not actually on LFS because it's a file that existed before I uploaded new .pdf files to LFS. But because this file is not on machine 2, when I try to do git pull, LFS is saying oh it should be in LFS because of the .pdf extension but I can't find this file. If this is not how it works, I have no idea why this error is happening.

Comment: Git just stores files in commits. The way Git-LFS lies to Git is by *replacing* a "good" file with a "pointer" file. The pointer file is not useful, *except to Git-LFS*, which treats it as the instructions to retrieve the real file from the LFS server. Git thinks that the pointer file is the "good" file to store inside Git, even though it isn't. So Git never sees the real file, just the lies. Note that if you install just Git, and use that, you'll see all the bad (pointer) files, none of the good (content) files.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Git LFS, there is a single remote, which is usually *origin*, from which data is pulled.  This error messages means that when you checked out the branch in question, the object that was supposed to be downlaoded didn't exist on the server.  Usually this is because nobody has pushed it there.  If you are self-hosting the LFS server, it's possible that the object has been deleted or otherwise lost, but major forges shouldn't have that problem.

If you have the object in another checkout (such as on machine 1), you can run `git lfs push --all` to push any objects up to the server and then try to do a  `git lfs pull` on the other machine (machine 2).  If you don't have this object elsewhere, then the data is lost.

Normally you should not need to manually push LFS objects because hooks are installed automatically that should do that for you.  However, if you haven't run `git lfs install` at least once on that machine (or otherwise set up the filter programs properly), then Git LFS won't have been invoked, and the hooks won't have been installed.

Comment: "Nobody has pushed it there" is correct because test.pdf existed on master before I installed LFS and existing files do not get uploaded to LFS (old files are not tracked by LFS right?). Does doing `git lfs push --all` add old .pdf files too?

Comment: If `test.pdf` existed on master before you used LFS, it wasn't an LFS file, and it has no bearing on your question.  Once it became an LFS file, it should have been pushed to the remote if the hooks were installed.  `git lfs push --all` will push all objects in the history which exist on the current system.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow sorry.. total noob. Do you mean I need to make it an LFS file somehow and then do `git lfs push --all` to solve the problem of "object not found"? (btw I edited the question for clarity)

Comment: No.  Your file is already an LFS file, or you wouldn't have seen this error.  Go to machine 1 and run `git lfs push --all`.  Then go to machine 2 and do `git lfs pull`.

Comment: Ah, I have another problem, because I cannot do Git LFS pull on machine 2 (I cannot install LFS on machine 2 because of access restrictions). I had proceeded because I heard that technically you do not need to install LFS on multiple machines, just 1. I have to find another way, thanks anyway for your help, I wish I could use your solution

Comment: So you are saying that `git lfs push --all` will push to LFS even old files that wasn't pushed after LFS was integrated to the repo? I didn't think it could do that, because I read this page that said the only way to upload old files is to "rewrite history" https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#adding-git-lfs-to-a-pre-existing-repo .

Comment: What you're asking in the comments is really appropriate for a new question and can't be answered fully here.  I will tell you that I am the primary maintainer of Git LFS and this is the recommended approach to fix the problem.  If you want to know more about how things work in your particular case, please ask a new question.